# Rest Api File Upload with version comments

Tags: rest, file-upload

Is there an api to upload a file along with Version Comments?

When I upload a file through the SharePoint portal, the file upload popup also provides a text box to include version comments if needed. I am expecting the File upload REST API to have an equivalent parameter but I am not finding it. Currently what we do to upload - Do a HTTP post with the file content to the below API

_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{0}')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='{1}')

Is there a way to post Version comments too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/checkin(comment='Check-in comment.',checkintype=0)` OR `/publish(comment='Check-in comment for the publish operation.')` OR `approve(comment='Check-in comment for the approval.')`

For example:

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{0}')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='{1}')/publish(comment='Check-in comment for the publish operation.')
```

More information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx

Comment: Check in, publish and approve are meant for different purposes. My requirement is to upload a file with version comments. I want to know if i can pass the version comments as a parameter while calling the add method to upload the file!!